# How to encrypt web.config connection strings without recycling the app pool

Tags: asp.net, iis, encryption, web-config, kentico

## Goal

Break the **connectionStrings** section out of the **web.config** by placing it into an [external configuration file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx) *while* being able to [encrypt/decrypt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx) the connection strings on the fly *without* causing the application pool to recycle (which creates an undesired service outage).

## Attempt #1

1. I broke the connectionStrings section out by copying it into a newly created **connectionStrings.config** external configuration file and then replaced it with `<connectionStrings configSource="connectionStrings.config"/>` in the web.config
2. After the sites came back up, I ran `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "connectionStrings" %path_to_web.config_folder%` via the command prompt to encrypt the connection strings

### Result

The websites temporarily stopped responding immediately after running the above command because the app pool recycled due to a web.config change. However, I checked and the web.config was only "touched," i.e. the file's Last Modified Date got updated although its content didn't actually change. *The connection strings in connectionStrings.config were successfully encrypted, though!*

I figured there might have been some fundamental feature/limitation of **aspnet_regiis.exe** which automatically touches the web.config after doing its thing, so I looked for an alternative approach to encryption. This led me to...

## Attempt #2

1. I opened the web.config in the [Microsoft Enterprise Library Configuration tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15104) (ran as administrator)
2. Chose the **RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider** option from the drop-down as the Protection Provider under the **Database Settings** block
3. Saved the file

### Result

Doing this literally took the connectionStrings block from the connectionStrings.config file and inserted it *back* into the web.config encrypted. This circumvented the whole point of using an external config and defeated the purpose of trying this approach out in the first place!

## Question

Is it even possible to encrypt web.config settings without having the app pool recycle before taking effect? I can't find this answer in Microsoft's documentation or anywhere for that matter.

Thank you!

Comment: are you sure you did it?

Comment: It shouldn't take a server reboot to re-read your web.config. Restarting the app should do it, and I'm certain an IIS restart will.

Comment: Running the aspnet_regiis command above changes the "last modified" date of both the external config and web.config files. The web.config's content doesn't change, but the web app recycles/restarts due to the web.config "modification."